# Getting default render device on Vulkan

Tags: vulkan

I have an OpenGLES based engine that creates EGLSurface objects from EGLDisplay objects obtained via eglGetDisplay with EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY parameter.

Now I want to port the engine to Vulkan and among the gpus the vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices method returns me I want to choose the default gpu preferably in the same manner as eglGetDisplay chooses its device internally.

Is there a concept of a default device under Vulkan and how would one identify it?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

There isn't officially a concept of a default device. However, several drivers install implicit layers that re-order the physical device list so that the first enumerated physical device is the preferred one. The [VK_MESA_device_select layer](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/commit/?id=9bc5b2d169d3a3c9d52fc30987eaba52e3b7dc00) is a typical example. So if the first physical device meets your requirements and you don't have a particular reason to choose a different one, that should be good default.